# How to remove "\" character from a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `\"somedata\"`. I want to remove **"\"** character to result as `"somedata"`. I tried `var mystring = mystring.replace("\","");`,however the result is incorrect. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add complete code

Comment: @Tushar The wrong way of escaping is the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character. To use `\`, you need to escape it twice:

```
mystring.replace("\\","");
```

**Explanation**

When you give this:

```
mystring.replace("\","");
```

The JavaScript thinks, you wanna insert a `"` there and will not find the ending double quotes. The string will be incomplete here.

```js
var some = '\\"somedata\\"';
alert("Before: " + some);
some = some.replace("\\", "");
alert("After: " + some);
```

But the above code replaces only one occurrence. You need to use RegEx to replace all the occurrences.

```js
var some = '\\"somedata\\"';
alert("Before: " + some);
some = some.replace(/\\/g, "");
alert("After: " + some);
```

You can use the `g` tag for global.

Answer (score 3):

try following:

```
mystring.replace(/\\/g,"");
```